# "Майдан": с какой буквы писать?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Я тоже задам вопрос на актуальную тему. А именно: когда речь идет не о площади как части города, а как о символе переворота (хунты, революции - кому как нравится), как нужно писать слово "майдан": в кавычках или без, с большой буквы или с маленькой?
Спасибо

Comment: гостиница "Майдан"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.В данной теме  важно отличать термины (нарицательные  существительные)  от имен собственных. Нарицательные  имена существительные – это названия РЯДА однородных предметов со сходными признаками,  а собственные имена  относятся к ЕДИНИЧНОМУ  (конкретному) предмету из этого ряда.
НАПРИМЕР: античный мир, средневековье, наполеоновские войны, но:  эпоха Просвещения, эпоха Возрождения, Версальский мир,  Первая мировая война. Интересно, что изменение оценки события влияет на его написание: гражданская война 1918-1920 (в советское время), но: Гражданская война в России (современное название).

2.Слово «МАЙДАН» может иметь разное написание:

А) майдан как нарицательное существительное (строчная буква)  -  городская торговая площадь, также (перенос по смежности) люди, собравшиеся на этой площади.

Б) Майдан, Евромайдан   –  конкретное политическое движение, массовая многомесячная акция протеста  центре Киева, начавшаяся 21 ноября в ответ на  в ответ на приостановку украинским правительством подготовки к подписанию соглашения об ассоциации между Украиной и Евросоюзом. Кавычки как дополнительное выделительное средство здесь не требуются.

В) «майдан»  как нарицательное существительное с новым значением – массовые протестные акции такого рода, например: «Киевский «майдан» невозможен в других странах». Кавычки обозначают условность  нового значения слова.

Г) Также антимайдан (или «антимайдан») – разовые выступления противников Майдана: «Значительно более ярким событием стал антимайдан в Севастополе».  Наличие кавычек может зависеть от тематики текста.

3.Термин «ОРАНЖЕВАЯ РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ»  существует преимущественно как термин (нар. сущ.), обозначая определенный характер подобных революций (широкая кампания мирных протестов, митингов, пикетов, забастовок - в частности (на Украине)за признание недействительными официальных итогов голосования и проведение повторных выборов. Также цветными революциями стали называть ненасильственное свержение существующей власти. В статусе имени собственного (конкретного политического движения) название "Оранжевая революция" используется не часто.

Answer (score 2):

*Майдан*, *Евромайдан*, как пишутся названия исторических событий. Но *"оранжевая революция", "революция роз"* и т. д., так как это не бесспорные революции (ср.: *Октябрьская революция*). Здесь слова употреблены в условном значении (применительно к ситуации или контексту).

Дополнение для тех, кто не считает слово "революция" в данном контексте условным: если бы это было так, тогда писали бы *Оранжевая революция* или *"оранжевая" революция*.

Comment: Вот не понял, какая связь "небесспорность" имеет к заглавной...
Это безотносительно к оценке их роли.

Comment: Октябрьская революция - это действительно революция. А оранжевая и другие цветные, видимо, не совсем (или их статус пока не определен). Иначе писали бы: Оранжевая революция.

Comment: Не понимаю. Ексли бы бело было в статусе писали бы Оранжевая не-совсем-революция. Заглавная пишется когда объект становится именем собственным, а не когда мы не определились, что оно есть. 
Тунгусский метеорит - с заглавной? А сто оно такое, никто до сих пор не знает.  
Грамота предлагает писать со строчной, но в кавычках: "оранжевая революция". Это более разумно. Тут претензия на то, что "оранжевый" эпитет просто не прошел до конца стадию онимизации (перехода в имя собственное). Можно спорить. но это будет содержательный спор. А вот насчет "недостаточности революции" - странновато звучит.

Comment: >Октябрьская революция - это действительно революция.

Вопрос крайне спорный. Последние лет 30 в среде историков активно обсуждается, можно ли считать события октября 1917-го революцией или это только переворот.

Comment: Ну какой же это переворот, если изменился общественный строй?

Comment: Если бы проблема была только в том, что "оранжевый" не перешло в имя собственное, то писали бы: "оранжевая" революция.

Comment: Марк Из, хорошо бы для начала уяснить разницу в понятиях. Я что-то так и не понял, в чем разница между "Октябрьским переворотом" и "Октябрьской революцией", кроме словесного жонглирования.

>>Если бы проблема была только в том, что "оранжевый" не перешло в имя собственное, то писали бы: "оранжевая" революция.  
  
Не вижу логики. Хотя в принципе в ряде случаев Грамота так и рекомендует.

Comment: >Марк Из, хорошо бы для начала уяснить разницу в понятиях

@behemothus, разницу я позже объясню в ответе к своему вопросу, пока нет времени.

>Ну какой же это переворот, если изменился общественный строй?

@виктор1799, если очень коротко, то сторонники "переворота" указывают на то, что изменение общественного строя произошло уже в ходе Февральской революции, а большевики лишь захватили центральную власть в ходе достаточно локальной операции в Петрограде.

Comment: Захватили  власть  и  изменили  общественный  строй.  Правда  после  победы  в  гражданской  войне.  Но  началось-то  в  октябре.

Comment: @bernard, так вопрос как раз в том когда началось в октябре или в феврале.

Comment: Последним комментарием все-таки брошу свои пять копеек. Если я вдруг буду решать, с какой буквы писать фамилию Имярекова Такоя Сякоевича, то месяцем его рождения я поинтересуюсь в последнюю очередь. если вообще поинтересуюсь. Аналогично и с "Октябрьской" революцией, которая произошла то ли в ноябре, то ли в феврале. февральская, кстати, тоже в марте была.

Comment: Октябрьская  революция  -  это  революция  и  по  отношению  к  Февральской  тоже.